# Protractor: Could not find update-config.json

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have converted my Cucumber tests running through Protractor to TypeScript. If I run the tests from the commnad-line, like this:

```
rimraf cucumber/build && tsc -p cucumber && protractor cucumber/build/protractor.conf.js
```

This is fine, runs the tests successfully and correctly. However, if I move these command into a script, like this:

```
// package.json
...
"cucumber": "rimraf cucumber/build && tsc -p cucumber && protractor cucumber/build/protractor.conf.js"
...
```

then it falls over with the following error:

```
[13:54:55] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:54:55] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[13:54:55] E/direct - Error code: 135
[13:54:55] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[13:54:55] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
```

I am very new to Protractor and Cucumber, and Selenium, so I have no idea what to do! I have tried running the update command but it has no effect.

My protractor.conf.ts looks like this:

```
import { Config } from 'protractor';

export let config: Config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    '../features/**/*.feature'
  ],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--disable-gpu"]
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json')
    });

    const chai = require('chai');
    const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

    // Load chai-as-promised support
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

    // Initialise should API (attaches as a property on Object)
    chai.should();
  },
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
      './features/**/steps/*.steps.js'
    ]
  }
};
```

Can someone help?

Comment: can you show the protractor config. Also as the error says, run the webdriver-manager update command so it can generate webdriver config file with the location of browser drivers itself.

Comment: Ok, added; and as I said in my original post, I have already tried running the update command.

Comment: execute the following command: node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

Answer (score 0):

This is as `npm` `scripts` designed. If you define cmd in `scripts` block in `package.json`,  npm will try to find the executable binary used in cmd from project local package folder which is `<folder of package.json>/node_modules/.bin`.

When you enter and execute `protractor cucumber/build/protractor.conf.js` directly in cmd window, the executable binary: `protractor` at here is find from `PATH` environment variable, not from project local package folder.

This is the difference of finding `executable binary` in `scripts` of package.json and not in package.json.

To fix your issue, you should execute webdriver-manager update for project local package, this will create the `update-config.json` into project local package folder.

```
"cucumber": "rimraf cucumber/build && tsc -p cucumber && webdriver-manager update && protractor cucumber/build/protractor.conf.js"
```